# React native bottom navigation ( screen animation )

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I started learning react native, and I have no experience with mobile as much as I have experience with react for web applications.

I am trying to do the navigation as in the video below. I also want to have screen animations (left, right).
Is it possible to do this in react native? Does anyone have any idea?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I found this [tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-implement-an-animated-tab-in-react-native-c1952ad7103e), see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use [material bottom tabs navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/) for navigation and [react-native-animatable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable) for transition animation. If you don't prefer default animations of animatable, you can create your own.